# How to only delete vertices where the Polyline doesnt bend

Tags: arcgis-10.4, vertices

I am working on pipes and I only need vertices where the lines bend. A lot of my pipe have vertices in the middle of the polyline even though there isn't a bend.

Is there any way to delete them with out me going through every polyline 1 by 1?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 with an Advanced level license.

Comment: What platform are you using? ArcMap has a Simplify tool that should do what you want but you need to specify your GIS and version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned you are using Arcmap. Use **[Simplify Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/cartography-toolbox/simplify-line.htm)**, part of the  **Generalization Toolset**. It sounds to me like using the "POINT_REMOVE" option is enough for your purposes. Use an extremely low tolerance to make sure that subtle bends do not get removed, you might have to play with this parameter a bit, as your "straight" lines may not be always as straight as they seem.